# How can I define a javascript variable on a webpage in selenium using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, variables

So I'm trying to execute a script on a webpage in Python that just declares a js variable with selenium.
My code:

```
driver.execute_script('var apikey = 30')
```

Nevertheless, when I try to call the variable it somehow says it's undeclared, really weird.
How would I define a js variable on a webpage using selenium?

Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the `execute_script` method runs as a body of an anonymous function ([link](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))).

If you need to declare a global variable, explicitly assign it to the `window` variable:

```py
driver.execute_script('window.apikey = 30')
```